# Juntar todos los elementos en un div

Tags: php, css, html5, bootstrap-4

Tengo un `div` en donde presento otros `div` a manera de botones, cuando los botones superan el alto del `div` que los contiene, quedan apilados en la parte de arriba [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] pero cuanto son pocos, se crean espacios entre las filas distribuyendolos dentro del div que los contiene [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], lo que deseo es, que siempre queden aplilados en el `top` del div que los contiene [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo el siguiente codigo,

`Div` que contiene la lista de botones

```
 <div id="divButtonList" class="row">
 </div>
```

Codigo `php` que genera la lista de botones

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE prd_Activo=true AND prd_group=" . $prd_group . " ORDER BY prd_name";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->rowCount();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $product = '
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addPct" id="product-' . $row['prd_id'] . '" onclick="addItemOrder(' . $row['prd_id'] . ')">
                    <div class="card alert bg-light">
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <div class="product_name">
                                    <h6>' . utf8_decode(ucwords(strtolower($row["prd_name"]))) . '<br><span style="font-size: xx-small; color:red;">' . strtoupper($row['prd_brand']) . '</span></h6>    
                                </div>
                                <div class="product_des">
                                    <h6>' . $co_money . number_format($row['prd_pricesell1'], 2) . '<span style="font-size: xx-small;"> X ' . $row['prd_UnidadEmpaque'] . '</span>' . $iconFav . '</h6>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        ';

    echo $product;
}
```

Y con jquery lleno el `div divButtonList`

```
$('#divButtonList').load('PosProductButtons.php?prd_group=' + id_group);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparte de

```
     <div id="divButtonList" class="row">
     </div>
```

Necesitas colocar el respectivo container, intenta esto y puede que te funcione.

```
     <div id="divButtonListContainer" class="container">
         <div id="divButtonList" class="row">
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: Habia probado quitandole la clase row, pero queda mejor asi por que se conservan la propiedades del container...